# jboss-deployment-structure.xml configuration

Tags: java, jboss, migration, classloader, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate an application from JBoss AS 6 to JBoss AS 7.
The application that I am trying to migrate has dependencies on others projects.
Due to the new class loader in JBoss AS 7 I have to add explicitly the dependencies on jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

It not very clear for me how to do this task.

My project structure looks like this:

I have 3 independent jars: Creative.jar, JAXB.jar, Client.jar.    One jar that has dependencies on all three of them: MDB.jar.             An war who has dependencies on Creative.jar and Client.jar: Used.war   And finally I have to create an ear using this ant build:

```
zipfileset refid="Creative.jar" prefix="lib"     
zipfileset refid="Creative.lib.files" prefix="lib"      
zipfileset refid="JAXB.jar" prefix="lib"     
zipfileset refid="MDB.jar"    
zipfileset refid="Where.war"    
zipfileset refid="Client.jar" prefix="lib"    
zipfileset dir="EarContent" includes="**/*
```

I have no idea what to add inside my jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [developer thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/202130) or [AS7 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) to know more about jboss-deployment-structure.xml.